# Captioning side by side figures

Tags: graphics, captions

I need to get two figures side by side and I am using the following code:

```
\begin{figure} [H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{1e4}
\caption{Combined figure}
\label{fig:left}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{1e3}
\caption{Right figure}
\label{fig:right}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

However, I need to caption each figure independently. How can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean with *individually*? Both have their own caption, right? Or do you want to replace the word `subfigure` with `minipage` to get `1` and `2` instead of `a` and `b`?

Comment: With `subcaption` package you can get it ...

Comment: No I need both having their own caption, eg: Figure 1 and Figure 2

Answer (score 1):

You can use `minipages` inside the `figure` environment with a `caption` command for each figure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

As you can see in figs.~\ref{fig:left} and \ref{fig:right} \dots

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Left figure}
\label{fig:left}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Right figure}
\label{fig:right}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to do with the `floatrow` package, which is is dedicated to that, cooperates with the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\DeclareFloatVCode{rowsep}{\vskip 5ex}

\begin{document}



\begin{figure} [H]
  \centering\floatsetup{floatrowsep = qquad, rowpostcode = rowsep}
  \begin{floatrow}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{For the Snarks were Boojums, you see…}\label{fig:left}}
    {\includegraphics[width = 0.48\textwidth]{snark.png}}
    %%%%
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{A Portrait of a distinguished author}\label{fig:right}}
    {\includegraphics[width = 0.48\textwidth]{Charles-Dodgson}}
  \end{floatrow}

\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
{\includegraphics[scale = 0.8]{sendak}}
{\caption{Where Wild Things are} \label{fig:Maurice}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]
{\includegraphics[scale = 0.5]{AliceSteadman}}
{\caption{Ralph} \label{fig:Wabbit}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! and if I want four more rows for instance?

Comment: One  `floatrow` environment per row… (as long as they fit an the page). Take a look at the doc for setting parameters; there are many interesting examples, including mixing several types of floats, or beside caption. I'll add an example with two rows in a moment.